# re running testng-failed.XML in same Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

After executing test cases through Jenkins job  is there a way to run testng generated testng-failed.XML in post build section and publish rerun reports also? I have to do it in the same job. I shouldn't trigger another job for this. Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Are you using Maven or another build toolchain for your builds?

Comment: Yeah I am using maven only.

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows, it will execute your testng-failed.xml file after testng.xml. The file should exist by the time its turn to execute comes. It will be executed only once.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <configuration>
                <!-- Sets the VM argument line used for unit tests are run. -->
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    <suiteXmlFile>target/surefire-reports/testng-failed.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

*******UPDATE
Implement a TestNg listener IReporter and configure it in your original testNg.xml file

It's method

```
 GenerateReport()
```

Is invoked once all suites have run. In this method you must implement back up functionality of the generated testng-failed.xml .
Once this is done, testNg will proceed to rerun the testNg-failed.xml file  as per my previous mentioned Maven configuration.

Comment: Thanks!!! But I should get first run reports and testng-failed.XML reports also . If we run failed.XML immediately the old reports will be overwritten. I was copying reports to a specified location using apache in post build section. I have to get both reports.

Comment: RaviTeja posted the final correct answer.  Read it once more and you will have the solution.